# transform array data using php

Tags: php, laravel

```
            [original:protected] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 65751
                    [social_id] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [org_id] => 1
                    [type] => 3
                    [s_id] => 1
                    [role_id] => 0
                    [active] => 1
                    [name] => RX
                    [first_name] => JJ
                    [last_name] => DKL
                    [email] => first@testmail.com
                    [secondary_email] => 
                    [username] => cLvcyUr2

                )


    [1] => User Object

                (
                    [user_id] => 82197
                    [social_id] => 
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [org_id] => 1
                    [type] => 2
                    [s_id] => 1
                    [role_id] => 0
                    [active] => 1
                    [name] => sec
                    [first_name] => XX
                    [last_name] => J3
                    [email] => first@testmail.com
                    [secondary_email] => 
                    [username] => VfTqXyvJ

                )
```

How to transform the array data mean to keep only two email and username rest should remove

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [email] => first@testmail.com
    [username] => cLvcyUr2
    )
[1] => Array (
    [email] => first@testmail.com
    [username] => VfTqXyvJ
    )
)
```

How could this possible i do not to unset data one by one it should automatically unset and pick only two value

Comment: simple you can select specific columns in query .`User::get(['email', 'username'])->toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an empty array and just copy the values you need? Trying to unset everything in your array is a lot of work and is not really maintainable, out of experience.

Note that your pasted code contains both an array and object, but your question is about an array only.

```
$newArray = [];

foreach ($oldArray as $item) {
    $newArray[] = [
        'email' => $item->email, 
        'username' => $item->username
    ]; // If $item is object
    $newArray[] = [
        'email' => $item['email'], 
        'username' => $item['username']
    ]; // If $item is array
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: setting only one value not setting other

Comment: Seriously? `// Same for username`. With all due respect, but if you can't even figure out how to do the username, please take a couple of decent programming courses. These are the basics of the basics.

Comment: Your output will be something like this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => ss ) [1] => Array ( [username] => dd )  [2] => Array ( [email] => ff) [3] => Array ( [username] => nn))` array manipulation wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that :

```
$index = array_search('user_id', $array);
unset($array[$index]);
```

Do that for all key you want to remove.

Comment: this is worst way

Comment: It isn't exactly the worst way, but it's kind of the unmaintainable and nuclear option. Nothing wrong with that, but I wouldn't recommend it indeed.

Comment: Still this will not work as it is multidimensional array it require a foreach() loop then unset() the index value

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = [];

foreach ($oldArray as $item) {
$arr = [];
    $arr['email'] = $item->email;
    $arr['username'] = $item->username;

    $newArray[] = $arr;
}
```

Comment: why don't you write only one line for the code inside the foreach() `$newArray[] = array('email' => $item->email, 'username' => $item->username)`

Comment: That also can doable,